# Bluemix Internet of Things Platform GitHub repository edit code setting up workspace stalls at loading resources

Tags: github, ibm-cloud, iot

Newbie question. I have spent hours on it and searched help.

In **Bluemix**, I created a new **IoT** Platform  and  created a new GitHub.

Then I went to "Edit Code."

Setting up Workspace stalls at "loading resources".

I have enabled 3rd party cookies and tried 4 different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Explorer in that order).

I cannot get it to work.  I believe there is something incorrectly configured on my computer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I just tried this and it worked fine for me.  Do you have any errors in the log you can share so we can assist with troubleshooting?

Comment: The page will run forever trying to 'Loading Resources." The only message I get on that page is when I try it later. While 'Loading Resources" at the bottom of the page is a message "Looking for project (correct account) | (correct workspace)".

Comment: Also: When I click on Git URL       I eventually get message "Unable to display repository contents at this time. Refresh the browser to try again."  Refresh does not work.  FYI: Running Windows 10 Enterprise on Surface Pro 3   Also:  Works on my phone but not a great work environment. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I suggest you may want to open a support ticket.  You can do that from your Bluemix console in the top right by clicking under your account ID then support "get help".